# How to allow react-native to enable support for JSX (extension) files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

React Native app fails to resolve components.

I am trying to import & render `Test.jsx` inside of `App.js`.

I get the following error-

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./screens/Test` from App.js`:
The module `./screens/Test` could not be found from App.js. Indeed, none of these files exist
```

Project Manager(or rather files) look like this-

[image: Files]

Code of Test.js-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Hello World?</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

Code of App.js-

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Test from "./screens/Test";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Test />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

I've literally tried every solution mentioned - [react-native#4968](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968) and none of them seem to work.
I've also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246677/i-am-getting-the-module-index-css-could-not-be-found-from-react-native), but, the solution is for css and nowhere close to what would fix this issue.

I've looked at lot more issues and SO's with no clue what else I have to do. I've also created a new project(screenshot and code is from the new project).

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**
I realised that the issue was because I have `.jsx` extension. Imports are working fine for `.js` file. Any pointers on how to enable the project to accept `.jsx` for imports?

Comment: Are you using webpack to build the app? If so, show us your module loaders/rules

Comment: @bozzmob Maybe this can help: http://www.fallingcanbedeadly.com/posts/enabling-react-native-jsx-extension

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**update**: **for RN >0.59** as @RedGaint pointed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55134051/8034782 you need to configure `metro.config.js` in the root level.

```
  module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    /* resolver options */
   sourceExts: ['jsx','js'] //add here 
  },
  transformer: {
    /* transformer options */
  },
  serializer: {
    /* serializer options */
  },
  server: {
    /* server options */
  }

  /* general options */
};
```

**For RN < 0.57**:
   Inside of the root of your project add a file named rn-cli.config.js and place the following code into it.

```
// ./rn-cli.config.js
module.exports = {
  /// @description Allows you to enable support for JSX files
  /// The `index.js` file in the root of your project has to be `.js`. 
  getSourceExts: () => [ 'jsx', 'js' ],
}
```

**For RN > 0.57**:

```
  module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js'],
    },
  };
```

for more reference look into this there is already an issue opened:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5233#issuecomment-382083236

Comment: @aravind_reddy I just tried it, it does not work even after having cleaned up everything and even trying on a fresh new project. It complains to be unable to find the file (and listing a bunch of file extensions it tried, not including those I put in `getSourceExts`). I tried to make a syntax error in this file and the `getSourceExts` function, which prove me it was indeed called, but nonetheless not taken into account to resolve files.

Comment: can you explain what is the exact problem ?

Comment: @aravind_reddy I also added it in `metro.config.js` still no luck.

Comment: Just realized adding `resolver` object in `metro.config.js` gives me an error that it can't resolve imports in `App.js`

Answer (score 26):

I am using `react-native 0.59` and `metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.0",`.

The `./rn-cli.config.js` file no longer works in the IOS release build. RN 0.59 requires a config file called [metro.config.js](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/blob/eba55f3287bbd1993fce45f172f3e8760c544406/RnDiffApp/metro.config.js) in the root level. I have to use it to enable JSX support instead of `rn-cli.config.js`. Check out the documentation for the config file: https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/en/configuration.html

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
    transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: false,
            },
        }),
    },
    resolver: {
        sourceExts: ['jsx','js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the config schema was changed in 0.57 version: [#248](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/248)

Try this:

```
// ./rn-cli.config.js
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 5):

### If someone doesn't want to load the default config and spread it, then they can simply use this

In `metro.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: [
      'js', // note this has to be defined first or you get an error
      'json',
      'jsx',
      'mjs',
      // required because the react-native cli ignores `resolverMainFields`
      'ts',
      'tsx',
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This works in ReactNative v0.63

```
// metro.config.js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');
module.exports = (async () => {
  const { resolver: { sourceExts } } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return { resolver: { sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'jsx'] } };
})();
```

*Note: This approach will not overwrite existing settings.*

Answer (score 0):

Setup for **React Native version 0.73.1**

`.eslintrc.js` file setup

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    extends: '@react-native',
    plugins: ['jsx'],
};
```

`tsconfig.json` file setup

```
{
    "extends": "@react-native/typescript-config/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```