# Can't import react component from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I opened a new react native project using expo (Boilerplate).
I added a new component named 'Test' and I cant import it from Homescreen.

this is `Homescreen.js` :

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import {Test} from '../components/test/Test';

export const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Test/>
    </View>
  );
};
```

`Test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export const Test = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Test Works!</Text>
        </View>
    )
};
```

When I build the project I get the following error:
`Unable to resolve "../components/test/Test" from "screens/HomeScreen.js"`

I want `Test` component to be on the same structure as above (const with an arrow function).

What am I doing wrong? How can I import Test?

Thanks!

Comment: That error means that the path to `test.jsx` is incorrect when you are importing. Please check that

Comment: Checked. The path is correct.

Comment: The error means just that. Can you go to commandline switch to the `screens` folder and then try `cd ../components/test/`. It should change the directory without any error.

Comment: It really changed the directory without any error like you said. So I tried to change the path to be: `import {Test} from '../components/test/' `, but I got the error: `Unable to resolve "../components/test/" from "screens/HomeScreen.js"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

React Native doesn't recognize jsx files by default. You can either change the file to Test.js or refer to this [How to allow react-native to enable support for JSX (extension) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311473/how-to-allow-react-native-to-enable-support-for-jsx-extension-files)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Test.jsx` exports only the component `Test` and not an object(`export { Test }`). While importing, use

`import Test from '../components/test/Test'`

instead of

`import {Test} from '../components/test/Test';`

Comment: `export const Test` they're doing a named export, not a default export, so this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

put '../components/test' instead of './components/test'
add another dot.