# Error: Unable to resolve module ./navigators/MainNavigator from G:\Workspace\FormApp\App.js:

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, dependencies

I am working on this react native project and it is giving me the below error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./navigators/MainNavigator from G:\Workspace\FormApp\App.js:

None of these files exist:
  * navigators\MainNavigator(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * navigators\MainNavigator\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  1 | import React from "react";
> 2 | import MainNavigator from "./navigators/MainNavigator";
    |                            ^
  3 |
  4 | export default function App() {
  5 |     return(
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (G:\Workspace\FormApp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:107:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (G:\Workspace\FormApp\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
```

This is my App.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import MainNavigator from "./navigators/MainNavigator";

export default function App() {
    return(
      <MainNavigator />
    )
}
```

This is my Main Navigator file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Home from '../src/screens/Home'
import Colors from '../src/constants/colors'

export default function MainNavigator() {

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    return (
            <Stack.Navigator
              initialRouteName = 'Categories'
              screenOptions = {
                {headerStyle: {backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor}, 
                  headerTintColor:'#ffffff', 
                  headerTitleStyle : {fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Bold'},
                  headerBackTitleStyle: {fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Bold'}}}>      
                <Stack.Screen 
                  name="Categories" 
                  component={Home} 
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

These are the dependencies present in My package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1"
  },
```

This is my project structure
[image]
App is working fine when all the code is in App.js, but it is not working and giving me the above error when i am trying to get the code in to a separate component and then tries to import it to App.js. I have tried everything I knew but it is not working. If anybody knows something about it please help.

Comment: Have you checked that all characters in `"./navigators/MainNavigator"` are all exactly the same as on the file system ? It is case-sensitive for both file names and folder names.

Comment: Make sure your "./navigators/MainNavigator" is the exact relative path to the MainNavigator from your App.js file. If fine, you may also check the answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737609/unable-to-resolve-module-react-navigation

Also, it would be helpful if you can share your folder structure of the application so folder structure can be verified by someone else apart from you.

Comment: @abj1305 I added the project structure

Answer (score 0):

This is dafault export issue. You can either write export default MainNavigator at the last line of your Main Navigator.js file or you can import {Mai Navigator} from your_component_path to resolve this issue. Make sure to try any one solution of these two solutions at one time

Comment: I have already written export default function MainNavigator.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this error, I just had to change the file extension from .jsx to .js and Boom! it was working. :-}

Comment: Maybe could also have worked if you wrote your import statement like this:- `import MainNavigator from "./navigators/MainNavigator.jsx"; `

Comment: Because I think by default `MainNavigator` would mean `MainNavigator.js`. So yeah, you would have to write `MainNavigator.jsx` if you are importing a JSX file.

Comment: I do that too but it was not working

Comment: React Native doesn't supports JSX imports by default. Here's the same question asked. You can do some configurations to allow JSX imports: -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311473/how-to-allow-react-native-to-enable-support-for-jsx-extension-files